# How to make webdriver wait 2 sec before closing using testNG, annotation afterMethod?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng, wait

I use testNG, I click on link on website and in my afterMethod i want it to wait 3-4 seconds before closing.

I added the following to the afterMethod, but now it closes even faster than without this wait.withTimeout()

```
@Test
  public void main() {

      WebElement vse_speci = firefox.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href=\"/astana/#specialists\"]")) ;

      vse_speci.click();
      String vse_speci_url = firefox.getCurrentUrl();

      String expected_url = "http://test.naimi.me/" ;
      Assert.assertEquals(vse_speci_url, expected_url );

  }
  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod() {
      firefox = new  FirefoxDriver() ;
      firefox.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      //Launch the website
      firefox.get("http://test.naimi.me");
  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void afterMethod() {
      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(firefox,1);
      wait.withTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      firefox.quit();

  }

}
```

Comment: Use    firefox.close(); instead of    firefox.quit(); OR just remove    firefox.quit();

Comment: @HelpingHands, this is not a solution, i need some wait function....

Comment: Try implicit wait then..like this firefox.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: I think you misused WebDriverWait(please check the javadoc of its  super class FluentWait at: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sure `Thread.sleep(2000);`

```
 @AfterMethod
  public void afterMethod() throws Exception{
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      firefox.quit();

  }
```

Comment: Using Thread.sleep(2000); for two seconds will not hurt your execution.

Comment: Does sleep method do not stop script execution??

Comment: It just makes your execution pause for defined amount of time. It will not stop it completely. That's why I added my reason to use Thread.sleep() in comment.

Comment: Then same as wait.Whats diff?